# Reconnecting the system

Tags: linux-mint, kernel-panic

I cannot boot inside my Linux Mint Rebecca 17.2 although, when booting from live CD. I can access both `root` and `home` partitions (and swap-space). The problem happened after repartitioning my disk. Because I want to avoid format, do you know any way I can fix it?

`fsck` didn't work for me when just doing: `~fsck /dev/sda9`

When I press <kbd>enter</kbd> for Linux Mint 17.2 Cinammon on grub, I get a kernel panic.

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities of what could be going wrong here are too numerous to count.  If you can access your data from a live CD copy it off somewhere and re-install.  Even if you manage to get it to boot again you'll probably have a lifetime of errors related to whatever it was that caused this.  Save yourself the time and re-install now.

Comment: Often in a while I have some kernel updates gone wrong, or some dkms that did not install ok, and *normally* an update-grub2 ; grub-install is more than enough to keep it going. Although I agree that if you do not know what you are doing, your recommendation can be the best course of action.

Comment: I'm curious how that would help in this situation?  The error was caused by a re-partition and he's now getting a kernel panic which means grub is successfully loading the kernel and it's a known good kernel since it used to boot.

Comment: You are absolutely right, no use.